# Ask for certain credentials when trying to open a file on windows

Tags: powershell, credentials

I have a file on windows 7 and what I want to do is once someone tries to open this file I want a window to appear asking for the username and password (which is not related to the windows credentials, these credentials would be stored somewhere in another file) and depending on the username and password entered a file will be copied from one location to another. So for example, if userA logged in with passUserA then fileA will be copied to a destination folder, if userB logged in with passUserB then fileB will be the one copied to a destination folder. Any thoughts please how this can be done?

Comment: Make the file an encrypted zip archive.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers thanks for your suggestion, any other way around it? as I prefer not to make it as a zip file because it's a shorcut to an application (.exe).

Comment: What is this .exe? In house, something you have control of?

Comment: @AustinFrench thanks for your comment. It's an open source software I used for doing the task. It can be installed and it also has a portable version.

Comment: Any insight into what the program does? How will the powershell script *really* provide any level of security other than obfuscation? What happens when the user right clicks the script and lifts the exe path?

Comment: @AustinFrench The program is blender 3d for modelling. So I have two startup files/scenes, so what I want is when a person clicks on it's shortcut or exe it will ask for credentials and then depending on the credentials a certain startupfile will be copied to the correct destination where blender use it as a startup and then blender will be opened.

Comment: Additional question, why use a username and password and not just present a selection choice for which configuration the user needs: `1) Design Team 2) Animator`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126169/discussion-between-tak-and-austin-french).

Comment: @AustinFrench because one startup file will be for a kind of expert who have access to all controls and the other one will be just a very simple a basic startup file with only simple controls. And I don't want to give the simple user the option of choosing being an expert.

I've contiuned the discussion in the above link if you could please have a look.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers also if I did it as a zip file how I'm gonna copy a certain file to a certain location depending on the username and password entered?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and describe in more detail what you actually want to achieve.